# Baby Rudin Definition of Order

Tags: real-analysis, order-theory

At the start of Baby Rudin (Walter Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*), Rudin defines an order $<$ on a set $S$ as being any relation which obeys the following two axioms:

(1) One and only one of $x<y, x=y, y<x$ is true.
(2) If $x<y$ and $y<z$ then $x<z$.

My question is, to what notion of order (in order theory) does this correspond? Is it a total order (which is defined as a relation which is reflexive, transitive, antisymmetric, and strongly connected)?

Comment: It is not a total order. Clearly we do not have $x<x$.

Comment: @beeclu Of course, I should have seen that! I've come across the notion of "strict total order". Is this correct? The reason I ask is that Rudin later proves that $\mathbb{R}$ is the unique complete ordered field (up to isomorphism) and I want to ensure I understand what the "ordered" caveat there means.

Comment: I am not familiar with order theory, but from the definition of "strict total order" on wiki these seem to be equivalent notions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an alternative description of a total order.

Usually an order on a set is defined as relation $\le$ which has suitable properties. One can then define $x < y$ iff $x \le y $ nd $x \ne y$.

If $\le$ is a total order, then $<$ clearly satisfies Rudin's two axioms. Conversely, given Rudin's relation $<$, we can define $x \le y$ iff $x < y$ or $x = y$. It is an easy exercise to verify that $\le$ is a total order.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I agree that $\leq$ is a total order but Rudin is working with $<$ as the primary order of interest. Would it be possible to comment on $<$ in particular?

Comment: It is a total order. Note that Rudin uses $=$ as well. By using $=$ in the first axiom, he's informally defining $\leq$ without ever using the symbol.

Comment: @EE18 Working with relations $<$ or $\le$ is a matter of taste. As I wrote, they can be transformed into eacb other without loss of information. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364289/strict-partial-order.

Comment: I see, thank you!